# Error fetching Account Info on Android Kotlin `java.nio.BufferUnderflowException`

Tags: metaplex, buffer

I want to fetch an account's data using [Metaplex KT Library][1].

I am still facing error while fetching an account:
code:

```
try {
             val serializer = SolanaAccountSerializer(BorshAsBase64JsonArraySerializer((ProgramInfo.serializer())))
                val account = solana.api.getAccountInfo(serializer, getProgramInfoPda().address).getOrThrow()

                Log.d(TAG, "fetchQuestionCount: ${account}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "fetchQuestionCount Error: ${e.message}")
         }
```

Context: ProgramInfo is my own class:

```
@Serializable
data class ProgramInfo(var author: @Contextual PublicKey, var question_count: @Contextual Number, var bump: @Contextual Number) {
}
```

This is the error:
`Error: Size must be known in advance when using READ_ALL`

Comment: Did you check if the account exists? Can you send the address and network?

Comment: @JonasH. 
Devnet
9eESgm63H5DvRvZNczdJ8HvHf2VoA93m5Rw6Y5QMu9Z

Account exists

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what the problem is, but maybe you need to use another Serializer. What kind of account is it? Anchor?
Then maybe

```
SolanaAccountSerializer
```

is what you are searching for.

Comment: how do i use this?

Comment: I was just looking this up in the kotlin sdk source code: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ametaplex-foundation%2FSolanaKT%20SolanaAccountSerializer&type=code maybe give it a try.

Comment: I did some edits and now i am getting different error. I am able to fetch a wallet account (as its data is null)